# PAYU Payment Gateway Google Analytics Referral Problem

Tags: google-analytics

We are using PAYU Payment Gateway. We already Setup Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce but in Acquisiton Overview When We Click the "Referral" we see secure.payu.com.tr instead of referral website like facebook, instagram etc. We do not want to see payment gateway referral but original referral. Hope there is a solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is of course, using PAYU's API and build your own payment gateway so that the user never leaves your site.

You can try adding payu to the [referral exclusion list](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en).
The above won't solve everything(you might still see it as direct traffic), but it should help. Puting some events on the "pay" buttons on your site before they get to payu will also help.